# A question on Nekovar's paper Belinson's Conjectures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motives

In Section 2 of Nevovar's paper ["Beilinson's Conjectures"](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/refs/BeilinsonintroII.pdf), for a pure motive $M$ of the form $h^i(X)(n)$ where $X$ is a projective smooth variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ is an integer such that the weight $w=i-2n$ is negative. Then Deligne's period map is defined to be
\begin{equation}
\alpha_M:M_B^+ \otimes \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (M_{dR}/F^0 M_{dR}) \otimes \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
where $M_B$ is the Betti realisation of $M$, $M_B^+$ is the subspace of $M_B$ on which $\phi_{\infty}$ (induced from the action of conjugation on the complex-valued points $X(\mathbb{C})$ and on $\mathbb{Q}(n)=(2 \pi i)^n \mathbb{Q}$ ) acts as identity, $M_{dR}$ is the de Rham realisation of $M$ and $F^0$ is a subspace of $M_{dR}$ appears in the filtration. This homomorphism is induced from the standard comparison isomorphism $I_\infty$ followed by a quotient.

In the commutative diagram in section 2.2 (top of page 7), it claims that the following sequence is exact
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow (F^0M_{dR} \oplus M_B^+)\otimes \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (M_B^-(-1) \oplus M_B^+ ) \otimes \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \text{Ker} (\alpha_{M^\vee(1)})^\vee \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
The weight of the pure motive $M^\vee(1)$ is $-w-2$, which might not be negative, but the period map is still defined to be 
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{M^\vee(1)}:M^\vee(1)_B^+ \otimes \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (M^\vee(1)_{dR}/F^0M^\vee(1)_{dR}) \otimes \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

**Question**: How to prove the above short sequence is exact?

Two lines below the commuative diagram in page 7, it says that

"similarly, $\text{Coker}(\alpha_{M^\vee(1)}) \xrightarrow{\sim} \text{Ker} (\alpha_M)^\vee=0$"

which the author deduces from the commuative diagram. If assume $\text{Coker}(\alpha_{M^\vee(1)})=0$, I know how to show the above short sequence is exact. But without this assumption, I don't know how to prove the the short sequence is exact from the definition of $\alpha_{M^\vee(1)}$ directly!

Comment: Just dualize the sequence and note that $F^0M_{dR}$ is the dual of $M^\vee(1)_{dR}/F^0M^\vee(1)_{dR}$. Your confusion may be because the standard indexing of the filtration on the dual ensures that $F^1M^\vee_{dR}$ is actually the annihilator of $F^0M_{dR}$. Therefore you need to twist $M^\vee$, which then makes $F^0M^\vee(1)_{dR}$ the annihilator instead.

Comment: @KeerthiMadapusiPera Thank you. What still confuse me is that the injectivity of the left map of this short sequence is equivalent to $\alpha_{M^\vee(1)}$ being surjective, but I don't know how to prove $\alpha_{M^\vee(1)}$ is surjective!

Comment: By duality, it's equivalent to $\ker \alpha_M$ being $0$; that is, to $M^+_B\otimes\mathbb{R}$ (which is contained in $M_{dR}\otimes\mathbb{R}$ under the comparison isomorphism) intersecting trivially with $F^0M_{dR}\otimes\mathbb{R}$. But in fact, $M_B\otimes\mathbb{R}$ intersects trivially with $F^0M_{dR}\otimes \mathbb{C}$ when $w<0$, as can be checked from the fact that the latter cannot contain both of any conjugate pair of weights.

Comment: @KeerthiMadapusiPera Ifeel very sorry to ask you again, by which duality? Could you explain more carefully why it is equivalent to $\text{ker} \, \alpha_M=0$?

Comment: The map $\alpha_{M^\vee(1)}$ is just the dual of the map $\alpha_M$, and so is surjective precisely when $\alpha_M$ is injective.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make any sense. What's correct is this: The dual of $\alpha_{M^\vee(1)}$ is the map $F^0M_{dR}\otimes\mathbb{R} \to (M_{dR}\otimes\mathbb{R})/(M_B^+\otimes \mathbb{R})$. The kernel of this is the same as the kernel of $\alpha_M$.

Comment: Another way to see this is to note directly that the first map in the purportedly exact sequence is $F^0M_{dR}\otimes\mathbb{R}\oplus M^+_B\otimes\mathbb{R}$ mapping to $M_{dR}\otimes \mathbb{R}$, and so is injective precisely when $F^0M_{dR}\otimes\mathbb{R}$ has trivial intersection with $M^+_B\otimes\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KeerthiMadapusiPera Thank you for your patience!